# How to return a View to a New/Separate browser window using an AJAX call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: redirectToANewWindow,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { filterValue: searchValue },
        success: function (result) {
            $('form').html(result);
        }
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult InitializeEditView(string filterValue)
{
  //some code
  return PartialView("PartialForm", model);
}
```

This works fine. It returns the updated view and paste it on the current page. But what I want to acheive is after it passes from the controller, the result should be rendered on a new/separate browser window. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)

Comment: I'm passing a model to that new window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you would like this form to create a new window? Get rid of the jquery and just add this attribute to the form's html:

```
target="_blank"
```

as in

```
<form action="/yourcontroller" method="post" target="_blank">
...
</form>
```

EDIT:
You could feasibly do it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: redirectToANewWindow,
    dataType: 'html',
    data: { filterValue: searchValue },
    success: function (result) {
        var w = window.open();
        $(w.document.body).html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need any javascript for this, it's a standard form function.

Comment: From what I've read, target="_blank" will just create a new Browser Tab and not a new browser window. I haven't tried it though so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This is correct. In the case that you want to explicitly create a new browser window, you'll want to follow Mortalus' answer. There is no way to do it with "POST" that way though.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, if this is all on the same domain and protocol try the solution in my edit ^.

Comment: That's pretty neat. I think it'll work. I'll try it later. Thanks! :)

Comment: Cool, didn't knew Form elements accept 'target' attributes +1

Answer (score 4):

Currently you have decided to make an AJAX call and place the recived data in the form element by writing:

```
$('form').html(result);
```

in your AJAX success callback.

Don't use AJAX.. just open a new window with the required URL:

```
window.open('http:// ... my web?param1=0&param2=1')
```

This would require you to change the controller action to receive GET requests
and to return a full view.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult InitializeEditView(string filterValue)
{
  //some code
  return View("PartialForm", model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ajax here.You need to open a new window so you need simply trigger this

```
window.open('/ActionName/InitializeEditView??filterValue='+searchValue)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's not an AJAX post, if you want the whole browser window to update.

It's a standard HTML `<FORM>` post, change it to that.

[Edited]

OK, you want to open a *separate* window.  Do that as a GET with window.open(), or a POST via  jQuery & then put the HTML into it on success.

Comment: I dont want to update the whole window, I want to open a New Window and render the data that is processed from my controller on that separate window.

Comment: @Jude use jQuery Dialog then

Comment: @HaBo I would love to but my boss insists on using separate window just like Microsoft CRM..:/